# Asset folder path for c++ program [windows]

Tags: c++, sld

The structure of my Release version of my c++program is

```
 | bin
 | | game.exe
 | content
 | | sprites
 | | | asset.png
```

Within the code I pass the path to the asset as "../content/sprites/asset.png", but it is not found by the program. What am I doing wrong?

Extra info: I am using SLD2 as a supporting library.

Comment: The current directory when your program is run is not necessarily the directory containing your binary.  You can get this via [`GetModuleFileName (NULL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)

Comment: So the path to the asset should be relative to the binary or to the result of 
 GetModuleFileName?

Comment: You can derive the _directory_ containing the binary from the result of calling `GetModuleFileName`

Comment: So the path is the same as the one I assumed, now that this matter is solved - how do I pass a correct path to an asset?

Comment: Once you have the name of the directory containing your binary, you can append the same path as you were using before.

Comment: I can't use relative paths?

Comment: No, unless perhaps you set the current directory first, but that is fragile and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Then how can I distribute the program if the asset path is a constant dependent on my folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on the current directory being the directory containing your binary, but this is not always true.  Instead, you can do this (error and range checking omitted for brevity):

```
WCHAR buf = new WCHAR [32768];   // allow for long path names
GetModuleFileNameW (NULL, buf, 32768);
WCHAR sep = wcsrchr (buf, '\\');
wcscpy (sep + 1, L"..\\content\\sprites\\asset.png");
...
delete [] buf;
```

**Edit:**

If you are calling code that depends on the current directory being the one containing your binary, then you can do this instead somewhere in your initialisation code:

```
WCHAR buf = new WCHAR [32768];   // allow for long path names
GetModuleFileNameW (NULL, buf, 32768);
WCHAR sep = wcsrchr (buf, '\\');
*sep = 0;
SetCurrentDirectoryW (buf);
delete [] buf;
```

Again, I have omitted error and range checking for brevity.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input, but from what I see SLD's IMG_Load doesn't work with any path when used from an .exe

Comment: Updated my answer